# Visual Studio 2017 can not run MVC app in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome

[image: ErrorScreenShot]
I am trying to run ASP MVC application from Visual Studio 2017 in Chrome. I am always getting the attached error "This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action.Please install a program or,if one is already installed,create an association in the default programs control panel"(check screenshot). I can run my MVC app only if I select Internet Explorer or FireFox but not Chrome.
go to options->Debugging->Enable Javascript debugging in ASP.NET and try to run your web app in Chrome

Comment: to create a verifiable example just go to options->Debugging->Enable Javascript debugging in ASP.NET and try to run your web app in Chrome. You will get the same error. I think you should  not delete this question because it might help other people who might get this error with Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to turn off Javascript debugging :

> Options -> Debugging -> Enable Javascript Debugging in Asp.NET

[image]

I advise you to visit and read this article  "Client-side debugging of ASP.NET projects in Google Chrome : "
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the correct project is set up. (right-click the correct
  project in the project explorer then "Set as Startup Project").
- Make sure you are using the latest chrome version.
- Try to restart visual
  studio/computer
- Verify if you have the same problem with other project.